# Kimonolabs - is "Source URLs to crawl from another kimono API" dynamic

Tags: kimono

I've built two APIs with Kimonlabs.

API "A" gets a list of URLs.
API "B" gets several values from a web page.

I've set the crawl strategy for "B" to "URLs from Source API", and set the API to "A".

My question is about whether the list of URLs that "B" will process is dynamic, i.e. will the list change automatically the next time that "A" updates?  Or is the list of URLs static at the time I create B?

Answer (score 2):

Every API acts according it's settings:
"Specify how often this API will automatically fetch new data from the target page(s). APIs are limited to 1 URL for a hourly auto-run, <1000 URLs for a daily auto-run, and <10,000 URLs for a weekly auto-run."

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic. B will crawl the up-to-date set of URLs from A's last run.